# Собрать файл из частей воедино и вернуть его на клиент

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-5

У меня есть следующая задача

Есть файл, разбитый на части, каждая из которых загружена на сторонний сервер. Каждая часть файла может быть загружена в отдельный объект типа `Stream`. Задача состоит в том, чтобы каким-то образом собирать файл по кусочкам и возвращать его, на клиент, чтобы человек смог его скачать себе на устройство. При этом необходимо, чтобы не было ожидания, пока файл на сервере соберется по кусочкам и после этого отправится на клиент, поскольку:

- Это может занять много времени, поскольку файл целиком может занимать неограниченный объем памяти;
- Это может тратить много оперативной памяти также из-за возможного большого веса файла.

Мне представляется решение этой задачи примерно таким образом:

- Создается поток, куда будут последовательно записываться байты частей файла;
- Этот поток передается на клиент и начинается загрузка;
- По мере того, как на сервере скачиваются части файла, они записываются в поток (как только часть файла записалась в поток, клиент может ее скачать);
- Передача файла на клиент завершается и человек имеет у себя полностью загруженный файл.

Либо каким-то образом объединить несколько `Stream`, которые приходят с частями файла, в один

С самой сборкой файла по кусочкам проблем нет, проблема именно с последовательной записью данных в поток, откуда скачивает данные клиент. Подскажите, возможно ли в принципе решить такую задачу, и если возможно, то каким образом? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Извините, есть один вопрос и одно замечание. Вопрос: правильно ли я понимаю, что в момент, когда клиент обращается за файлом, все его кусочки уже есть на сервере, и вопрос только в том, как их собрать в один поток? Замечание:  по моему, Вам надо сделать несколько иначе. Как только открывается поток на клиента, на сервере открывается стрим, который читает первый кусочек, и Вы просто последовательно перекладывае из него содержимое в стрим, открытый на клиента. Закончился первый стрим - открываете второй кусочек, продолжая перекладывать содержимое... и т.п. Расход памяти будет близкий к нулю :-)

Comment: Нет, каждая часть файла лежит на удаленном сервере и ее получение осуществляется через интернет. Замечание верное, только я не могу понять, как это реализовать с технической стороны. По идее мне и нужно 100% того, что вы написали

Comment: Ну, задачка интересная, потому что позволяет прокачаться в том, как использовать очередь task'ов, и по завершению их дополнять поток "на клиента". я бы даже попробовал набросать своё решение, но, боюсь, меня обставят - есть тут очень профессиональные товарищи, которые просто на ходу такое накодят. Ну, примерно думать надо в этом направлении - запустить таски, ждать их завершения и дополнять поток на клиента. В зависимости от того, по памяти или по скорости надо оптимизировать - какчать куски или последовательно, или параллельно.

Comment: @S.H. тоже думал насчет последовательности тасков, но не укладывается в голове, как сначала отдать поток клиенту, а потом уже начать в него записывать данные